# Photoshop 'flow' not working

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, painting, brush-dynamics

I'm experimenting with flow in Photoshop, but can't seem to get it to work.

So I've selected a basic brush and set opacity to 100% and flow to 20%.

But even when I keep painting over the same bit, I just end up with a load of flat colour, instead of giving the effect that it's supposed to:

See the image below, I am trying to get an effect similar to that on the **left**... but instead I get what is shown on the **right**:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or could it perhaps be a bug? I'm using **Ps 19.1.0** if that helps

Comment: On the screenshot I see a stroke of a brush with low flow. This screenshot: is that an example of the effect you're expecting or your result? If it's something you're expecting, what's your result? If it's your result, what were you expecting?

Comment: If using mouse change brush hardness to 0%.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy thanks, Ive just updated my question! :)

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I've tried that too but no luck unfortunately

Comment: I could not replicate your issue. Try to reset the brush: Alt+0+0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While brush `Opacity` setting is absolute and works the same for any brush, `Flow` effect will look differently depending on a lot of other brush settings: `spacing`, `scattering`, `texture`, `dual brush`, etc...

In your example I'd think that `spacing` is set to a very low value so you don't really see any difference with high and low `flow`. Try openning Brush Setting window and changing `spacing` to something like 20-30%

[image]

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you!